# If database shows --None-- show pull down menu, if other show data entered

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu

I've come a long way with this script, but I am running into a new issue now. The data has posted correctly, but when I attempt to view the edit the pull down menu now shows --None-- even though the first name, "Any Kahl" is shown in the database.

The code below is what I'm using, I can't seem to understand why it's not pulling data the correct way. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
if ($row['fab1']=="--None--")
{
    echo'<div id="fab1">';
    $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME); 
    $mysqli->select_db('user');
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM user"); 
    echo "<SELECT name='fab1'>\n";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        echo "<option value='{$row['user']}'>{$row['user']}</option>\n";
    }
    echo "</select>\n";
    echo '</div>';
}
else
{
    echo'<div id="fab1">';
    $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME); 
    $mysqli->select_db('user');
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM user"); 
    echo "<SELECT name='fab1'>\n";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        echo "<option value='{$row['user']}'>{$row['user']}</option>\n";
    }
    echo "</select>\n";
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't wrap your code blocks in curly braces, the if statement will only apply to the first line immediately following it (in your case: `echo'<div id="fab1">'`), anything after that will execute regardless of whether your statement evaluated to true.

You should wrap your if statement in curly braces:

```
echo '<div id="box4">';
echo '<h2>Fabricators</h2>';
if ($row['fab1']="--None--")
{
    echo'<div id="fab1">';
    $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME); 
    $mysqli->select_db('user');
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM user"); 
    echo "<SELECT name='fab1'>\n";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        echo "<option value='{$row['user']}'>{$row['user']}</option>\n";
    }
    echo "</select>\n";
    echo '</div>';
}
else
{
    echo '<div id="fab1"><span class="b"></span><input type="text" name="fab1"  size="20" value="' . $row['fab1'] . '" /></div>';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) That is the problem with learning from websites, http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_if_else.asp this place normally does right by me, but for some reason it didn't tell me to encapsulate like you said to.  Although I thought it was odd, the site had never let me down yet.

Comment: @MattRidge - Please please please don't use w3schools! They're full of false info, which will only cause you trouble down the line. The fact that they haven't let you down yet is not enough. Trust me, one day you'll get really burnt by them!

Comment: I've learned that, but is there anywhere else to go to get information of the sort except here? I don't mind asking, but my work sees me do it at times and they think I'm on facebook even though I'm not.

Comment: @MattRidge - You should really get used to using the [PHP Documentation](http://us.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php). They have pretty much everything you need.

Comment: Updated, can you check out the changes and see what is happening now?

Answer (score 1):

You need to encapulate the statements between the if and the else.

this can be done in a few different ways.

```
if (condition) : 
//statements if true
else : 
//all other statements
endif;
```

or

```
if(condition){
//statements if true
}
else {
//all other statements
}
```

The way you have it written it only reads the first line after the if as part of the if statement. That is why the else statement is unexpected.